# Is there a way to disable IPv6 SLAAC on a per-interface basis in Debian?

Tags: debian, ipv6

I have a scenario where appliances running Debian may have multiple network interfaces.  I want my eth0 interface to get its address via SLAAC configuration, but I want the remaining interfaces to only have their link-local or manually configured IPv6 addresses.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I keep answering my own questions today!

Adding the following to the appropriate section /etc/network/interfaces does the trick, e.g. eth1:

> pre-up /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth1.autoconf=0

Found answer [here](http://lists.debian.org/debian-ipv6/2010/12/msg00004.html).

UPDATE: actually, that just disables the creation of an IPv6 IP address - it still gets, for example, default routes for that interface.  To disable SLAAC on the interface altogether, apparently what you *actually* want is net.ipv6.conf.eth1.accept_ra=0